# Spring boot oAuth2 "Bad Credentials" after successfull login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to secure REST api in my Spring Boot application by oAuth2 standard. I created classes extending AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter, ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and unfortunately it works only with login scenario. /oauth/token request returns access_token etc, but in every other case I get 401, Unauthorized, Bad credentials. I thought that wrong cliendId/secret was the case, but it would also affect login, right? 
P.S Application is connected to MySql database.

I already ran out of ideas, so maybe you guys are able to help me.

WebSecurityConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials", "password","refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ANDROID_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000)
                .secret("secret")
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(50000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.user.app"})
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManaget(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder, UserRepository repository) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(new UserDetailsServiceImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, somehow oAuth2 configuration was overwritten by base configuration in some places. Those places still weren't protected by oAuth, so that's why "Bad Credentials" error was occurring even after providing proper access token. Commenting configure() method inside WebSecurityConfig solved the problem.